# Assigning user input to object with variable in its index

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to using the JS to take user input and modify certain object attributes based on the user's input.  I am storing the object's index in the select's alt attribute in order to use that to update the correct object. I'm getting an error: element[Payment_Format_name] is undefined

The WF.php file takes data from a CSV and formats it into a mulch-dimensional object.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.getJSON('WF.php', function(data) {

    var newDiv, NewDiv2, NewDiv3,InvoiceInfo, count, DeliveryMethod, PaymentFormat, Payment_Format_id, Payment_Format_name;

    count = 0;

    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        count = count + 1; 
        //document.write (count);   

        newDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('row').appendTo('#showdata');

        newDiv3 = $('<div/>').addClass('hd').appendTo(newDiv);
        $('<div class="hd_field">' + element['PmtRec']['RcvrParty']['Name']['Name1'] + '</div>').appendTo(newDiv3);

        if (element['PmtRec']['PmtMethod'] === 'CHK'){

                $('<div class="hd_field">Delivery Method: <select alt="Delivery_Method" " id="Delivery' + count  +'" class="Delivery_Method"><option value="100" selected="selected">US Mail</option><option value="300">Foreign Mail</option><option value="J00">Certified Mail with Return Receipt</option></select><div id="Selected_Method' + count +'"></div></div>').appendTo(newDiv3);
        }
         else if (element['PmtRec']['PmtMethod'] === 'DAC') {
                $('<div class="hd_field">Payment Format: <select alt="'+index +'" id="Payment_' + count  +'" class="Payment_Format"><option value="CTX" selected="selected">Company to Company</option><option value="PPD">Company to Person</option></select><div id="Selected_Format'+count+'"></div></div>').appendTo(newDiv3);

         }
        $('<div class="hd_field">' + 'Total: ' + element['PmtRec']['CurAmt'] + '</div>').appendTo(newDiv3);

        InvoiceInfo = element['PmtRec']['PmtDetail']['InvoiceInfo'];

        $.each(InvoiceInfo, function(index, element) {
        newDiv2 = $('<div/>').addClass('sub_row').appendTo(newDiv);
                $('<div class="field">' + element['InvoiceNum'] + '</div>').appendTo(newDiv2);
                $('<div class="field">' + element['NetCurAmt'] + '</div>').appendTo(newDiv2);
            });

        $('select.Payment_Format').change(function(){ 
            Payment_Format_id = ($(this).attr('id').match(/[\d]+$/));
            Payment_Format_name = ($(this).attr('alt')); 
            //alert(Payment_Format_name);
            PaymentFormat = ($(this).val()); 
            element[Payment_Format_name] = Payment_Format_name;
            element[Payment_Format_name]['PmtRec']['PmtFormat'] = PaymentFormat;
            $('#Selected_Format' + Payment_Format_id).text('Selected Format: ' + element[Payment_Format] );

            });

        });
            console.log(data);
     });

});
```

PHP (this is a snippet, I'm actually creating a lot more elements here)

```
     if (($handle = fopen('upload/BEN-new.csv', "r")) === FALSE) {
            die('Error opening file'); 
         }

         $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
         $cardCodes = array();
         $payments = array();
         $details = array ();

        while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",")) {
               $cardCodes[] = array_combine($headers, $row);

        }

            $prevCode = '';

            foreach ($cardCodes as $key => $value) {

                $payments[$value['CardCode']]['PmtRec']['PmtCrDr'] = 'C';
                $payments[$value['CardCode']]['PmtRec']['PmtFormat'] = 'CTX';
                                    fclose($handle);
                                    echo json_encode($payments)
```

Comment: What does the alert(Payment_Format_name); show? If you're using Chrome or something with firebug, do console.log(element) before you call element[Payment_Format_name] and see what value it has. Also, it seems a bit strange that you're accessing element['PmtRec']['PmtMethod'] at the start, and then element[Payment_Format_name]['PmtRec']['PmtMethod'], are you sure that's right?

Comment: console.log(element) prints out the entire object. Payment_Format_name only gets populated with user input, otherwise it's blank.  Also, this line element[Payment_Format_name]['PmtRec']['PmtFormat'] is supposed to update PaymentFormat for a particular object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so for starters,

```
$('select.Payment_Format').change(function(){ 
        Payment_Format_id = ($(this).attr('id').match(/[\d]+$/));
        Payment_Format_name = ($(this).attr('alt')); 
        PaymentFormat = ($(this).val()); 
        element[Payment_Format_name] = Payment_Format_name;
        element[Payment_Format_name]['PmtRec']['PmtFormat'] = PaymentFormat;
        $('#Selected_Format' + Payment_Format_id).text('Selected Format: ' + element[Payment_Format] );
    });
});
```

is not what you want - this function is reassigned to the change event of the `'select.Payment_Fomat'` element for each iteration of `$.each(data, function(index, element)`. The event listener should be added outside the `$.each` function, inside the `$.getJson` call and it needs to loop over the `elements` object, and try to find the correct data to update.

Apologies for the uselessness earlier, it was 5am and apparently I was slightly delusional.